# Socket programming, process blocked on select?

Tags: sockets, select, fork

I want do a simple program, where a father process create some child processes; before child pause(), they notification father process.
Child processes run correctly, but father wait on select, otherwise child have written on socket; where is the mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct{
    pid_t pid;
    int sockfd;
}Child;


void err_exit(char* str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


int convert_int(char* str)
{
    int v;
    char*p;

    errno = 0;
    v = strtol(str,&p,0);
    if(errno != 0 || *p != '\0')
        err_exit("errno");
    return v;
}



void child_job(pid_t pid,int sockfd)
{
    int v = write(sockfd,"1",1);
    if(v == -1)
        err_exit("write");
    printf("process %d in pause()\n",pid);
    pause();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     int nsel;
     fd_set  masterset;
     int n_child,i;
     int sockfd[2];
     pid_t pid;
     Child* c = NULL;

     if(argc != 2)
         err_exit("usage: <awake2> #children\n");
     FD_ZERO(&masterset);
     n_child = convert_int(argv[1]);
     c = malloc(n_child*sizeof(Child));
     if(c == NULL)
         err_exit("malloc");


     for(i = 0; i <n_child; i++){
         if ((socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockfd)) < 0) {      //create socket between child and father
              perror("errore in socketpair");
              exit(1);
         }
         if ((pid = fork()) > 0) {
             if (close(sockfd[1]) == -1) {  //father process closes sockfd[1]
               perror("errore in close");
               exit(1);
             }
             c[i].pid = pid;
             c[i].sockfd = sockfd[0];
             FD_SET(c[i].sockfd, &masterset);

         }
         else if(!pid)
             child_job(getpid(),c[i].sockfd);
     }

     for(;;){
         if ((nsel = select(n_child+1, &masterset, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
               perror("errore in bind");
               exit(1);
             }
         int i;
         for(i = 0; i <n_child; i++){
             if(FD_ISSET(c[i].sockfd, &masterset)) {
                 printf("changed fd\n");
             }

         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that's wrong is you're passing `c[i].sockfd` to `child_job()`. In the parent process, it was set to the first socket fd in the pair, but `child_job()` is called in the child process, where `c` never gets set to anything. You're passing the original contents of the `malloc` memory. Change that to `child_job(getpid(), sockfd[1]);` and you'll be getting closer.

Another thing is that the first argument to `select` is probably too low. `n_child` is the number of children, but you need to pass a number here that's greater than the highest file descriptor in your set. For example, run the program with the argument `1` so it creates 1 child. It is likely to start out with file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 open, so the socket pair will be file descriptors 3 and 4. The 3 goes into the `fd_set`, but the first argument to select is 1+1=2. select ignores your fd 3 because it's above the limit.

To fix that, create a new variable `int maxfd;` near your `fd_set`, initialize it to `-1` when you `FD_ZERO` the set, and after every call to `FD_SET`, update it:

```
if( [whatever fd you just gave to FD_SET] > maxfd)
  maxfd = [whatever fd you just gave to FD_SET];
```

and call select with `maxfd+1` as the first argument.

(Or maybe switch to `poll`)

That should get you far enough that your first select call works. After that, you'll find more problems.

The `fd_set` you pass to select will be modified (that's why you can do `FD_ISSET` tests on it afterward). If you go back to the top of the loop and pass it again without reinitializing it, select will not be looking at all the file descriptors any more, just the ones that were ready in the first call. To fix this, make a second `fd_set` and copy the master into it just before the select call, and never pass the master to select. (Or you can rebuild the set from scratch each time by scanning the child table.)

If you get a readable fd from select, you should read it before calling select again, otherwise you're just in a "eat CPU calling select over and over" loop.

Comment: The reason select wants the max fd plus 1 is that (in the original implementation at least) the kernel treats the `fd_set` as an array of bits with no inherent size limit. There are some implementations where you can enlarge the `fd_set` definition in your C program if the default size isn't big enough for all your fd's.. So the "max fd plus 1" just tells it where the array ends. It's exactly the same reason `read` takes a pointer and a size. Implementations that don't use an array of bits, or don't allow it to be resized, shouldn't really need the maxfd+1 but it remains part of the API